# ActorSystem in springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, akka

I am new to akka and springboot, while searching mostly examples inject ActorSystem with springextention, I tried like below and it's working. Just want to know if there is any difference or I might face any issues in future.

Get ActorSystem like below:

```
@Bean
    public ActorSystem getActorSystem() {
        // Create the actor system.
        final Config settings = ConfigFactory.load();
        return ActorSystem.create("my", settings);
    }
```

then where required just use like below:

```
ActorSystem system = context.getBean(ActorSystem.class);
ActorRef consumer = system.actorOf(Props.create(Consumer.class));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly fine if you are not using any beans in actors.
Otherwise, when you use context inside actors and you call  `context.getBean(SomeBean.class)` in any actor, you may face lifecycle issues.

`SomeBean` may not be yet loaded and initialized. Spring does not know that your `ActorSystem` needs `SomeBean` to be initialized first.
You may make your `ActorSystem` `@DependOn` all beans used by all actors, but this is fragile and hard to maintain.

Personally, I do not find Akka and (Spring+Java) to be good match. There is less friction when you use Akka with Scala language and ecosystem (libraries).